# Playwright's codegen's record function, gives "SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor ' >> nth=1'"

Tags: reactjs, testing, playwright

The issue is, I use Playwright's codegen to visit my website. Then everything is ok, except when I click "Record", few seconds later it gives me:

```
Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor ' >> nth=1'
SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor ' >> nth=1'
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at createTextMatcher (<anonymous>:5905:16)
    at Object.queryAll (<anonymous>:4910:29)
    at InjectedScript._queryEngineAll (<anonymous>:4855:49)
    at InjectedScript.querySelectorAll (<anonymous>:4842:30)
    at generateSelector (eval at extend (:5006:40), <anonymous>:929:32)
    at RecordActionTool._updateModelForHoveredElement (eval at extend (:5006:40), <anonymous>:3825:36)
    at RecordActionTool.onMouseMove (eval at extend (:5006:40), <anonymous>:3648:10)
    at Recorder._onMouseMove (eval at extend (:5006:40), <anonymous>:4325:71)
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at extend (:5006:40), <anonymous>:4218:68)
```

Things I tried

1. Googling, I find nothing.
2. Search for related keywords in my code. I find nothing.

Hints for the problem:

1. My website always run normally in normal browsers, never gave that error
2. That codegen browser's record function, never have problem with other websites, it only has problem with mine.
3. I don't use ordinary method to start codegen, as I need to run the chromium browser with '--disable-web-security', with below code:

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--disable-web-security']
    });
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto(`http://localhost:3000/xxxx`);
    await page.paused()
})();
```

4. I am using React to develop, and it is a webview that will be put in another mobile app.